# How do I configure Charles Proxy and Android so that I can view HTTPS sessions

Tags: android, proxy, charles-proxy

I want to view HTTPS sessions on my Android phone using Charles Proxy. I need to see the raw request/response contents for debugging my app. I've configured Charles by adding the host and port under "Proxy Settings" -> SSL Tab. When I run the app, all SSL calls seems to disappear quickly from the Charles. Does any one has any idea how to configure Charles Proxy and my Android device so they'll work together? Charles documentation doesn't have information for Android devices.

Comment: If you are on Android 7.0 you can find a solution at this link: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39227880/7220486)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured the issue. Its because Charles 3.7 has some bugs for Android devices. I updated to Charles 3.8 Beta version and seems to working fine for me.

Comment: I still see this issue with Charles 3.8b1 - with my setup it seems that in Android (using Galaxy Note/4.1.2) some of the HTTPS POST requests are lost - in iPhone 4S all is good.

Comment: it works on my Galaxy S3. I hope they fix Charles soon for Android devices.

Comment: @otso I meet the same trouble, some https can get and some unknow error. 
How is your problem solved?

Answer (score 100):

## for the Android7

refer to:
[How to get charles proxy work with Android 7 nougat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215229/how-to-get-charles-proxy-work-with-android-7-nougat)

## for the Android version below Android7

**From your computer, run Charles**:

1. Open Proxy Settings: Proxy -> Proxy Settings, Proxies Tab, check "Enable transparent HTTP proxying", and remember "Port" in heart. 
   [image]
2. SSL Proxy Settings:Proxy -> SSL Proxy Settings, SSL Proxying tab, Check “enable SSL Proxying”, and add *.* to Locations:
   [image]
   [image]
3. Open Access Control Settings: Proxy -> Access Control Settings. Add your local subnet to authorize machines on you local network to use the proxy from another machine/mobile.
   [image]

**In Android Phone**:

1. Configure your mobile:  Go to Settings -> Wireless & networks -> WiFi -> Connect or modify your network, fill in the computer IP address and Port(8888):
   [image]
2. Get Charles SSL Certificate. Visit this url from your mobile browser:
   http://charlesproxy.com/getssl
   [image]
3. In “Name the certificate” enter whatever you want
4. Accept the security warning and install the certificate. If you install it successful, then you probably see sth like that:
   In your phone, Settings -> Security -> Trusted credentials:
   [image]

Done.

then you can have some test on your mobile, the encrypted https request will be shown in Charles:
[image]

Comment: I'm using Charles 4.1.3 and in Help menu, it tells me to `Configure your device to use Charles as its HTTP proxy on 10.72.xx.xx:8888, then browse to chls.pro/ssl to download and install the certificate.` It works in my iPhone but not Android. In my Android, I visit the old url `charlesproxy.com/getssl` works.

Comment: On Android 6.0 chrome browser when I went to http://charlesproxy.com/getssl , it has shown static page "Charles SSL CA Certificate installation..." and didn't start certificate download. Please clarify what needs to be done in this case ?

Comment: I could solve above problem with below steps 1. remove existing charles certificate ( corrupted/expired/etc ) 2. enable proxy in device 3. download new certificate ( funny thing here as below; on one android "charles-proxy..certificate.cer" gets downloaded and on other "charles-proxy..certificate.pem" gets downloaded.  4. From Chrome browser trying to open .pem file gives error message. 5 .Now directly goto file location through File Manager.   6.  Tap on it and give new name as Charles, it gets installed and you can see the traffic in charles

Comment: @vikramvi , you might not download the cert file due to browser's security settings. in that case please try to use another browsers such as firefox,.....etc

Comment: make sure you run Adb commands   1) see the list of devices using adb devices . 2) adb reverse tcp:8888 tcp:8888 and install the SSLCertificate if not done previously.

Answer (score 46):

Edit - this answer was for an earlier version of Charles. See @semicircle21 answer below for the proper steps for v3.10.x -- much easier than this approach too... :-)

For what it's worth here are the step by step instructions for this. They should apply equally well in iOS too:

1. Open Charles
2. Go to Proxy > Proxy Settings > SSL
3. Check “Enable SSL Proxying”
4. Select “Add location” and enter the host name and port (if needed)
5. Click ok and make sure the option is checked
6. Download the Charles cert from here: [Charles cert >](http://charlesproxy.com/charles.crt)
7. Send that file to yourself in an email.
8. Open the email on your device and select the cert
9. In “Name the certificate” enter whatever you want
10. Click OK and you should get a message that the certificate was installed

You should then be able to see the SSL files in Charles. If you want to intercept and change the values you can use the  "Map Local" tool which is really awesome:

1. In Charles go to Tools > Map Local
2. Select "Add entry"
3. Enter the values for the file you want to replace
4. In “Local path” select the file you want the app to load instead
5. Click OK
6. Make sure the entry is selected and click OK
7. Run your app
8. You should see in “Notes” that your file loads instead of the live one

Comment: Step 4 is a bit tricky. If you want to allow ALL hosts then just don't add anything there! I was trying with "\*" and "\*.\*" and was getting a "The certificate file doesn't exist" error. Leaving the location section in blank solved for me.

Comment: This answer seems outdated. After upgrading to Charles 3.10, the Charles cert root file is generated for every pc/mac during the installation, you can export it from Help > SSL Proxying > Save Charles Root ....

Comment: @semicircle21 - you should add a new answer so it can be voted up

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, you need to save the .pem from the charles help menu and import that instead of the .cert download link

Comment: Easy to installed certificate on android is mentioned in answer by @User9527 please follow it than cumbersome email process

Comment: can no longer download cert from Download the Charles cert from here: Charles cert >

Answer (score 30):

Thanks for @bkurzius's answer and this update is for Charles 3.10+. (The reason is [here](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/additional/legacy-ssl-proxying/))

1. Open Charles
2. Go to Proxy > SSL Proxy Settings...
3. Check “Enable SSL Proxying”
4. Select “Add location” and enter the host name and port (if needed)
5. Click ok and make sure the option is checked
6. Go to Help > SSL Proxying > `Install Charles Root Certificate on a Mobile Device or Remote Browser...`, and just follow the instruction. (use the Android's browser to download and install the certificate.)
7. In “Name the certificate” enter whatever you want
8. Click OK and you should get a message that the certificate was installed

Comment: There is no "Enable SSL Proxying"

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Sorry for the mistake in Step2: 2. Go to Proxy > SSL Proxy Settings...

Comment: Note: In the "Add location" step, you can enter * as the host and 443 as the port if you want to enable SSL proxying for all HTTPS traffic.

Comment: Thanks for `Install Charles Root Certificate on a Mobile Device or Remote Browser...` where I found a correct IP address. But still can't install the certificate (Chrome doesn't download it). Only after Charles restart I could connect to the Net.

Answer (score 8):

See here:

http://jaanus.com/blog/2012/02/12/debugging-http-on-an-android-phone-or-tablet-with-charles-proxy-for-fun-and-profit/

You would need to install the charles.crt certificate to your device.

Comment: Ok - this symptom you would see if the cert is not there so hence proposing this solution.

Comment: It wasn't working for me until I also added " * " to my list of allowed SSL hosts in Proxy Settings

Comment: i'm afraid that link is now broken

Answer (score 8):

I wasted 1 day finding the issue , my system was not asking connection "allow" or "reject". i though it was due to some certiifcate issue .
tried all methods mentioned above but none of them worked . in the end i found "Firewall was real culprit ". if firewall settings is ON , they will not allow charles to connect with your laptop via proxy IP . make them off and all things will work smoothly .Not sure if that was relevent answer but just want to share.

Comment: I had same issue on my ubuntu machine. Tried debugging for many days. At last your solution worked. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @Abhishek glad my answer was helpful to someone in the community :)

Comment: I faced a similar issue and after some hours of struggle, I found the McAfee firewall to be the culprit.

Comment: @Sai : glad that helped you :D

Answer (score 4):

The top rated answers are working perfect (a bit old but still working), but I just want to mention that since Android N we all can configure your apps in order to have diff trust SSL certificates (for release , debug only and so on), including Charles SSL Proxy certificate (if you download the Charles certificate and put .pem file in your raw folder). More info can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

Also the official Charles documentation can be useful to setup this : https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

Hope this will help to setup Charles inside your app project not on every single Android device.

Comment: The second link says that Charles certificates are "uniquely generated for your installation of Charles", so they wouldn't be sharable between developers. Is that not the case? (i.e., Is there a universal Charles cert that I can use as described above?) @Stoycho Andreev

Answer (score 2):

For the newer emulator it might be helpful to launch from command line using:

`emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd <emulator_name> -http-proxy http://<ip-address>:8888`

Make sure you follow @User9527's advice above as well for the rest of the setup

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the IP address that charles was telling me to route to in my proxy settings was incorrect.  To solve I ended up going to `ifconfig` in the terminal and the trying the different IP addresses (listed next to `inet`) at port `8888` for the current active connections