# Why can't I see http or https traffic from Chrome Browser for Android on Charles Proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, charles-proxy

I've followed the directions from here:
[SSL Proxy/Charles and Android trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823434/ssl-proxy-charles-and-android-trouble)

I can see http and https requests from apps but I can't see any request from my mobile Chrome browser for Android come through Charles Proxy.

Comment: Did you figure it out?