# Charles Proxy + Android HTTPS

Tags: android, security, ssl, https, charles-proxy

So here are some similar but outdated answers that might have helped me few years/months ago:

[Why can't I see http or https traffic from Chrome Browser for Android on Charles Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170877/why-cant-i-see-http-or-https-traffic-from-chrome-browser-for-android-on-charles)

[How to get charles proxy work with Android 7 nougat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215229/how-to-get-charles-proxy-work-with-android-7-nougat?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I followed all of the instructions, I can read http requests fine, but not https requests. Still can't figure what I am doing wrong. There isn't much of my own to post since I have just followed the above guides.

I think the main issue is how do I force the app I am trying to debug to use my certificate? The manifest modifications don't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215229/how-to-get-charles-proxy-work-with-android-7-nougat) which has updated answers for Charles 4 and Android 7.

- You must install the cert from Charles help menu, and you must use Settings -> Security -> Install from storage on device.
- Your app needs a network_security_config.xml
- You must use a debuggable app

Answer (score 0):

For those who look for more recent Android Release (8,9,10 or ++) + CharlesProxy 4.6

Can refer this [guidethrough](https://dogcomp.medium.com/setup-charles-proxy-to-intercept-https-traffic-of-android-emulator-591baba5d7ec)...

Answer (score 0):

From Android N+, it requires extra steps to make it works.

1.Add res/xml/network_security_config.xml to your project.

```
<network-security-config>
<debug-overrides>
    <trust-anchors>
        <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
        <certificates src="user" />
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>

<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>

<domain-config>
    <!-- Make sure your URL Server here -->
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_production_domain</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="user"/>
        <certificates src="system"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
```

=> Make sure you replace your_production_domain with the domain that you would intercept

2.Add to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... >
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

If you could not make it works, you can check out the [sample code](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device/sample-android-project), which has all configuration.