# How to capture http traffic with Android Studio 2.1 and Charles proxy?

Tags: android, proxy, charles-proxy

I have updated the Android Studio IDE to the last version 2.1, and I want to capture the https traffic from the Android Emulator with the Chalres Proxy.

It looks that the emulator changed with the Android Studio 2.1, and I can't  find the way to capture http traffic with charles proxy.

In Stack Overflow there are some similar question but these are on older Android Studio versions, and I can´t find in that answers the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823434/ssl-proxy-charles-and-android-trouble) to use Charles proxy with Android API 23 emulator devices. For me it works for http. But for https traffic I get only unresolved IP addresses within the Charles session. Does anyone know how to support DNS with Charles Proxy, Android avd and https? I've made up a [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505406/analyse-https-traffic-of-android-6-emulator-with-charles-proxy) for my configuration.