# Android Studio network profiler

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a simple way to monitor network traffic with in Android Studio? I am looking for an equivalent of Firefox or Chrome's console where you can see REST HTTP calls: requests, responses and headers. I have tried the ADM (Android Device Monitor) and the "Network Statistics" but I don't see the detail of my HTTP calls.

Comment: I guess currently it doesn't have, however this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/38504376/2700586

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Android Official](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler.html#network_connection_troubleshooting), it only works for the app using HttpURLConnection and OKHttp libraries. If you are using other network library or the legacy apache HttpClient. It is not available to capture the network traffic.

> Network connection troubleshooting If the Network Profiler detects
>   traffic values, but cannot identify any supported network requests,
>   you will receive the following error message:
>
> "Network Profiling Data Unavailable: There is no information for the
>   network traffic you've selected."
>
> Currently, the Network Profiler supports only the **HttpURLConnection**
>   and **OkHttp** libraries for network connections. If your app uses another
>   network connection library, you may not be able to view your network
>   activity in the Network Profiler. If you have received this error
>   message, but your app does use HttpURLConnection or OkHttp, please
>   report a bug, or search the issue tracker to include your feedback in
>   an existing report that's related to your issue. You can also use
>   these resources to request support for additional libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Try Stetho from Facebook http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

> Network Inspection
>
> Network inspection is possible with the full spectrum of Chrome
>   Developer Tools features, including image preview, JSON response
>   helpers, and even exporting traces to the HAR format.

Comment: Stetho is having trouble with newer Chrome browsers and is becoming a bit problematic.

Comment: @Dejan, You can use the Edge browser. Stetho is working fine on Stetho.