# How to properly configure CharlesProxy on Android

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm using CharlesProxy v4.0.2 on a Pixel XL running 7.1.1 Nougat (this is not emulated).

I can connect the phone to charles just fine. I see all of the calls in the session view, but just the http. The problem is when I want to see what kind of call it is, it returns `<unknown>`.

I believe this is a problem with my SSL settings set on my Pixel (Charles works 100% okay with my iOS). I have SSL checked to On, and location as "*". I was able to download the .pem certificate from chls.pro/ssl. It is successfully installed on the pixel.

So, whenever I want to check an action in my app, Charles only returns `<unknown>`. Why, and what can I do to have it show all of the usual information?

Comment: You need to download the charles certificate for android, visit "http://charlesproxy.com/getssl/" from device

Comment: @Sanjeet Thanks! I have already done this, both manually through google drive, email, download directly, PEM and CER formats, the whole nine yards. No combination of them seem to work.

Comment: Also you need to add the action URL in Charles

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you are facing ? you have followed all the steps correctly , this should be working for you .

Comment: please check the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823434/ssl-proxy-charles-and-android-trouble/31945622#31945622

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a OnePlus 3 device with Android 7, after having SSL proxied with Charles successfully with dozens of different Android and iOS devices over the years. Not sure why my device won't trust the custom certificate, any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider that from version configured to "SdkVersion <= 23" we could see ssl traffic any without problems.
BUT for "SdkVersion >= 24" ssl traffic won´t be available for "User Certificate" (details at: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html).
If you need to see the message you need to modify your AndroidManifest.xml and add an network_security_config.xml configuration (Details at: http://ticketmastermobilestudio.com/blog/charles-proxy-with-android).