# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when using Charles with android(Kitkat)

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I am trying to perform a `M-I-T-M` using `Charles proxy` with my `android(Kitkat) device`, i have installed `charles Certificate` both in my Desktop and as well as in my mobile phone. I have also set `proxy manual` with ip of my Desktop and using port `8888` which is the default port to use charles, i have also added my mobile ip in my Charles with `enabling SSL proxy settings`. Now when i am trying to open any website in my desktop then everything is working fine, but the problem happening is when i am trying to open any `Https` website in my mobile then i am getting `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. I have seen many solutions and none of them are working for me.

I have also seen this post [SSL Proxy/Charles and Android trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823434/ssl-proxy-charles-and-android-trouble) and i have done the same thing which is mentioend in the answer but still i am facing this problem.

Anyone Please help me why this error is happening.

Comment: While your question does not specify if the problem is with Android 7 I assume it is. If not the second question contains some tips for older versions of Android which are related to the behavior of Charles. If you think that this is not a duplicate please edit your question to make it clear why the linked questions do not solve your problem.

Comment: sorry but i have updated it, also my question is different from the post you have commented.

Comment: In this case I removed the Android 7 specific question but take a look at the remaining one.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Look in my post i have done each and every step mentioned in the answer of the post you posted, but still i am getting this error, it's not a duplicate post and even if still you think it is then tell me how.

Comment: I've reopened the question then. Hopefully somebody can help you.