# charles ssl certificate installation on Android not working

Tags: charles-proxy

As per [SSL Proxy/Charles and Android trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823434/ssl-proxy-charles-and-android-trouble), I am trying to do setup.

Opening browser on Android phone and going to http://charlesproxy.com/getssl , downloaded file by name "charles-proxy-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem"

Tapping on this file gives error "The file format is not supported"

I'm having Micromax mobile + 5.1

Comment: My micromax with android 6 has the same issue with cert installation.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Device Setting.
2. Navigate to Security.
3. Scroll down the Security setting screen and under Credential
   Storage, tap on Install from SD card.
4. Select your certificate in file explorer and install it from there.

Checkout this link for learning more about Charles : http://myknowledgejunction.com/setting-up-mobile-device-to-use-charles/