# Charles proxy not showing traffic from Nexus 7

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, connection, charles-proxy

I am new to Charles Proxy and I have done the following so far :

1.Download Charles proxy

2.Install certificate in the laptop . Help -> SSL proxying -> Install Charles Root certificate

3.Disable Windows proxy

4.Added 0.0.0.0/0 to ACL settings

5. Get IP / port to configure HTTP proxy in my android device (Nexus 7)

In my Nexus 7, added Http proxy . Long press on my network , modify network ->advanced -> http proxy server name ( 10.x.x.x) port 8888

I am trying to install Charles proxy certificate in my Nexus 7 device however there does not seem to be any internet connection for it to download.  Nor do i see any traffic info in Charles proxy.

when i enter chls.pro/ssl it fails stating chrome didnt send any data. I tried with firefox however it fails with connection time out error.
I am losing internet connection when turning on http proxy.

In my Windows device , i turned on Routing and Remote access service. I tried to set Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters \ IPEnableRouter to 1 .

However I have the following issues :

1. Unable to see any traffic from android device in charles proxy
2. Android device seems to have no internet connection
3. Unable to go to chls.pro/ssl to dowbload certificate

I tried to look online but couldnt fix this

Windows 10 
Nexus 7 ( 5.0.2 )

Answer (score 0):

I can across a similar issue to what you mentioned in Issue #3. My device, which was running Android Marshmallow (6.0) was unable to install the the Charles Proxy certificate.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838010/charles-ssl-certificate-installation-on-android-not-working) fixed the problem

Comment: Thank you Austin. I think I found another thread that had the same solution however it did not work for me since the certificate was not downloaded in my case .. So I moved to Fiddler now..