# Can Charles still surface network traffic for third party apps on older versions of Android?

Tags: charles-proxy

Currently using Charles 4.2.1.

From the documentation:

> As of Android N, you need to add configuration to your app in order to
>   have it trust the SSL certificates generated by Charles SSL Proxying.
>   This means that you can only use SSL Proxying with apps that you
>   control. In order to configure your app to trust Charles, you need to
>   add a Network Security Configuration File to your app.

I used to be able to surface pings from third party apps on a device running Android 6, but it appears that functionality no longer exists. I have had a coworker replicate this same issue on devices set up with the general proxying workflow: [SSL Proxy/Charles and Android trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823434/ssl-proxy-charles-and-android-trouble)

Has anyone noticed that this capability has been lost on older versions of Android? Apologies for the newbish sounding question.