# Charles Proxy not working on Android emulator: No SNI provided; please fix your client

Tags: android, charles-proxy

1. I've started an Android 5.0 emulator.
2. Then I followed the steps [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823434/ssl-proxy-charles-and-android-trouble).
3. I get below error: No SNI provided; please fix your client

[image]

4. The Proxy has been setup correctly in the Settings of the emulator:

[image]

5. The certificate is installed on the emulator:

[image]

6. According to Charles, the Certificate is not correctly installed:

[image]

Comment: were u able to resolve