# Charles not working ,pop up "Allow" or "Deny" not coming

Tags: charles-proxy

1.Using Charles 4.2.6 version

Settings made:

2.Port number in Proxy setting < proxy < Http proxy :8888

3.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTDgE.png)

4.SSL Proxing setting < SSL Proxing < Enable SSL proxing < added *:*

5.Added VPN ip address in Access Control Setting

6.Installed and trusted Charles root certificate in windows system and my iOS device (XR Version:13.2.3)

7.Installed my test build

8.Changed ip address in configure device proxy (tried with VPN IP address and Normal IP address shown in Charles) Port 8888

9.Launched the test app

10.Traffic is not coming from test app to Charles.

11.Tried to uninstall and install Charles many times

12.Downloaded Charles root certificate in mobile through system (IE. transferred from system to mobile then trusted the certificate and enable the toggle)

13.Getting system calls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ542.png)

14. Prompt "allow" or "deny" is not coming after mapping ip address in iOS device.

Comment: Hey Anshu! Please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next question. Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL Proxy/Charles and Android trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823434/ssl-proxy-charles-and-android-trouble)

Comment: @Diggy.: If you have any doubt in my question let me know .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
I used [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner) to completely remove charles along with config/preferences.
And installed again, works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was restarting my router and do all these steps again.